# Adding credential files securely to Laravel Envoyer

Tags: laravel, envoyer.io, laravel-envoyer

I have an OAuth json credentials file I need Envoyer to add to each server on deployment.

I don't want to add it to git because it contains sensitive credentials.

How would I do this securely in Laravel Envoyer?